# module patterns javascript

Tags: javascript, module, closures

Trying out some examples and I get how it's getting the results.. but I am just not sure why anyone would do anything this way? Am I completely not understanding the point here?? What is it trying to accomplish by going through two object to get to console.log of baz? Why not do it on first bar ??

```
var foo = (function(){
       var publicAPI = {
           bar: function() {
               publicAPI.baz();
           },
           baz: function() {
               console.log("baz");
           }
       };
       return publicAPI;
 })();
 foo.bar();
```

Comment: I agree.  This overly complicated design pattern is used far too often when there is NO reason to use this extra complexity and something far simpler would accomplish all the programming objectives in a far simpler fashion.  There are occasionally reasons to use something like this, but when those reasons are not present, it seems counter-intuitive to add all the unnecessary complexity when it is simply not needed..

Answer (score 0):

To me it is an implementation of SOLID principles. You are correct that it could be applied to the initial bar. However, returning it and exposing it are two different responsibilities and as such should have separate implementations. Designing in this manner future proofs you in a way as you can now easily log using bar, but you can also inject baz into another function and use it to log there as well.

Another thought would be pseudo exposure. Baz is considered private and the global bar exposes it.